# My R Summary() of dataframe is not calculating strings correctly

Tags: r

I'm new to R, and new to posting on Stack Overflow. If I've made any mistakes please let me know.

I saw a number of examples for R's summary(df) function of dataframes. With numerical values it provides the quartile information, and with strings it provides a count of each strings occurrence. For some reason, on my computer I only get:

Private
length: df
Class: character
Mode: character.

[image: Screenshot of summary function]

Private
instead of
Yes: 565
No: 212

I searched through Stack Overflow, and looked at the documentation, but can't figure out what I did wrong, or what mistake I made while installing R to cause this.
 Thank you for your time.

Comment: `summary()` will provide a count of factor levels.  `Private` is a character vector, not a factor.

Comment: Thank you. Using as.factor() on the column in question returned the expected results. None of the tutorials I used had me take that step on the data they provided. Was there some change in the past that altered how csv files are read into R with read.csv()?

P.S. Thank you for editing my post to add the image.

Comment: There was indeed - From R 4.0.0 strings by default are kept as character class when using the `read.*()` functions.  Prior to that the default was conversion to factors.